# recommendation of the priority fees and regular fees

Tags: fees, priority-fees

I wanted to ask if there is a company that send me the recommendation of the priority fees, and regular fees to be the fastest in the block with API.

Answer (score 1):

Helius offers a API which will return the priority fees for a given program your want to interact with (or multiple), eg. you enter the Jup v6 swap program and it returns the priority fees for that program, etc.

https://docs.helius.dev/solana-rpc-nodes/alpha-priority-fee-api